# How to customize Laravel default notifications architecture along with custom columns in notifications table migration without repeating provided code

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-migrations, notification-channel

As Laravel shipped with a default `notification module`. It provides us following `notifications_table`.

| id | type | notifiable_type | notifiable_id | data | read_at | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fd71b94e-a0fc-42d5-9cfc-d0019cd83468 | Notifications\PushNotification | User | 23 | {"user_name":"Bak thonas","texts":"testing"} | null | 2023-01-09 12:43:02 | 2023-01-09 12:43:02 |

I added some custom columns by overriding the `notification-table` migration according to my requirement. After adding these columns `notifications_table` looks something like that,

| id | type | notifiable_type | notifiable_id | relation_type | relation_id | subject_en | subject_ar | message_en | message_ar | data | read_at | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fd71b94e-a0fc-42d5-9cfc-d0019cd83468 | Notifications\PushNotification | User | 23 | B | 22 | Welcome | مرحبا | Welcome to platform! | مرحبا بكم في Platform! | {"user_name":"Bak thonas","texts":"testing"} | null | 2023-01-09 12:43:02 | 2023-01-09 12:43:02 |

**Note:** I want to customize the default `database` channel shipped with `Laravel`. so this way I would just need to customize that `data-building` structure before storing it in a database instead repeating everything that is already provided in Laravel by default